# Nested functions in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for clarification on this snippet of code:

```
// Taken from alert create class call for clarification
_createClass(Alert, null, [{
    key: 'VERSION',
    get: function get() {
        return VERSION;
    }
}]);

return Alert;

// Taken from BS boilerplate
var _createClass = function () {
    function defineProperties(target, props) {
        for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
            var descriptor = props[i];
            descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false;
            descriptor.configurable = true;

            if ("value" in descriptor) {
                descriptor.writable = true;
            }

            Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor);
        }
    }

    return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) {
        if (protoProps) {
            defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps);
        }

        if (staticProps) {
            defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps);
        }

        return Constructor; 
    };
}();
```

I am unsure how the parameter `Alert`, `null` and the array object are passed to `createClass` when it does not take in any parameters.  I am assuming they get somehow get passed along the other nested functions, but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

`_createClass` is assigned the *result* of that function. That's because the function is an immediately invoked function expression ([IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)) - hence the `()` at the end of it.

So `_createClass` is really:

```
function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) {
  if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps);
  if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); 
  return Constructor; 
};
```

Comment: you're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I removed immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) wrapper

```
// Taken from BS boilerplate
var _createClass = function () { // <-- this
    function defineProperties(target, props) {
        for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
            var descriptor = props[i];
            descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false;
            descriptor.configurable = true;

            if ("value" in descriptor) {
                descriptor.writable = true;
            }

            Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor);
        }
    }

    return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) {
        if (protoProps) {
            defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps);
        }

        if (staticProps) {
            defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps);
        }

        return Constructor; 
    };
}(); // <-- and this
```

and moved the `defineProperties` function outside for clarity reasons.

But I need to say that IIFE wrapper is there in the first place for not leaking `defineProperties` function outside the IIFE. So basically IIFE is needed in most cases to encompass all private variables that are created once.

Other than that, please have a look at this debug style step by step refactored version.

```js
const defineProperties = (/*Alert*/target, /*[{...}]*/props) => {

  props.forEach(function(/*{...}*/descriptor) {
    // assigning false because we don't have it specified
    // in props object
    descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false;
    descriptor.configurable = true;
    
    // we don't have value either, so - skipping...
    if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true;
    
    // assigning VERSION prop with earlier decorated descriptor {...}
    Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor);
    // Now our Alert function has VERSION key, which returns 'VERSION' with its getter function

  });
}

const _createClass = (/*Alert*/Constructor, /*null*/protoProps, /*[{...}]*/staticProps) => {
  if (protoProps) {
    //not going here obviously because protoProps null
    defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps);
  }
  if (staticProps) {
    // going here because [{...}]
    defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps);
  }
  
  // returning class with decorated static property VERSION
  return Constructor;
};

_createClass(
  Alert, //Constructor
  null, //protoProps
  [{ //staticProps
    key: 'VERSION',
    get: function get() {
      return VERSION;
    }
  }]
);
```

Comment: @ConnerGesbocker no problem. If you liked our answers, please feel free to click the upvote arrow near the answers. And if you accept the answer click accept. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ConnerGesbocker just fyi  [example](https://fiverr-res.cloudinary.com/t_main1,q_auto,f_auto/gigs/5851521/original/python_-_Why_is__x__in___x____faster_than__x______x___-_Stack_Overflow.png)